# E-mail Regex causing catastrophic backtracking error

Tags: c#, regex, powershell, backtracking

I am at the verge of loosing my mind over trying to fix an Email Regex i built:

It is almost perfect for what i need. It works in 99.9% of all cases.

But there is one case which causes a catastrophic backtracking error and i cannot fix my regex for it.

The "Email" causing a catastrophic backtrack error:

`jasmin.martinez@tester.co.rolisa-brown.king@tester.co.ro`

Yes, such emails do occur in the application i need this Regex for.

People enter multiple Emails in one field for some reason. I have no answer for why this occurs.

I need the Help of Wizards of Stack Overflow.

My Email Regex might block or not block some officially valid Emails but that is not the point here.

All i want is to fix the catastrophic backtracking Problem of my Regex. I do not want to change what it blocks or not. It works for what i need it to do.

Here is my Email Regex:

`^[^\W_]+\w*(?:[.-]\w*)*[^\W_]+@[^\W_]+(?:[.-]?\w*[^\W_]+)*(?:\.[^\W_]{2,})$`

How can i make this Regex fail quickly so it doesn't cause a catastrophic backtracking error.

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!_)\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?<!_)@[^\W_]+(?>[.-]?\w*[^\W_])*\.[^\W_]{2,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJdWYO/5).

The main idea is introducing an [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), `(?>[.-]?\w*[^\W_])*` where backtracking is not allowed into the group pattern, and the re-vamped pattern before `@`: `(?!_)\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?<!_)`, that matches one or more word chars (while the first char cannot be a `_`) followed with zero or more sequences of `.` or `-` followed with one or more word chars that cannot end in `_`.

The `+` in `^[^\W_]+` is redundant, the next `\w*` already matches the same chars, so it can be removed. The same idea is behind removing `+` in `[^\W_]@`.

Note that the last non-capturing group is redundant, I removed it.

See the regex graphs:

[image]

and from debuggex:

[image]

An ASCII only version:

```
^(?!_)[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?:[.-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)*(?<!_)@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?>[.-]?[A-Za-z0-9_]*[A-Za-z0-9])*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. There are 2 Problems. My originial Regex did not allow any special characters like german umlauts [äöüß]. This Regex does allow them. I also tried to visualize this Regex on jex.im but it failed to do so. I would need a regex diagram for my documentation. Do you know of a Visualizer capable of this?

Comment: @Zombievirus 1. Your original pattern matches any Unicode chars since `\w` in .NET regex is Unicode aware. 2. I added the graph.

Comment: @Zombievirus I do not know of a regex visualizer that works that well for .NET compatible patterns. I just replace `(?>` with `(?:` and `(?<!` with `(?!` and then manually edited the text in Paint. But you might also like https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: Thank You Wiktor. I just double checked and you are right. My original Regex does allow for special charachters. May i ask if you know how i can allow only english charachters and [._-] in the email?

Comment: @Zombievirus You may simply compile the regex with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option. Then `\w` will only match `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Thank You Wiktor. I have no access to the code. The Developer made an extra conf file where i can change the regex anytime. This is why i need all the checks to happen in the regex itself. I can open a new Thread here for this new problem.

Comment: @Zombievirus Don't, it is easy to revamp. I added the ASCII only version.

Comment: Thank You Wiktor. It is perfect now. I upvoted your answer. Have a nice Day!

Comment: Or replace `\w` with an explicit set of characters. `[a-z0-9]`. The EcmaScript flag may also cause some other unexpected things.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ecmascript-matching-behavior

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this one:

```
^[^\W_](?:[\w.-]*[^\W_])?@[^\W_](?:\w*[^\W_])?(?:[.-]\w*[^\W_])*\.[^\W_]{2,}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bzVNd1/1

A comparison:

```
before: ^[^\W_]+   \w*(?:[.-]\w*)*[^\W_]+   @[^\W_]+              (?:[.-]?\w*[^\W_]+)*(?:\.[^\W_]{2,})$
after:  ^[^\W_] (?:[\w.-]*        [^\W_] )? @[^\W_] (?:\w*[^\W_])?(?:[.-] \w*[^\W_] )*   \.[^\W_]{2,} $
               ^   ^                    ^          ^      ^              ^   ^     ^  ^
               ^   ^                    ^          ^      ^              ^   ^     ^  No reason to use a group
               ^   ^                    ^          ^      ^              ^   ^     This quantifier was useless
               ^   ^                    ^          ^      ^              ^   If you want to match only letters before the possible [.-]
               ^   ^                    ^          ^      ^              Now, when you match [.-] there is no reason to make it optional
               ^   ^                    ^          ^      If you want to match only letters before the possible [.-]
               ^   ^                    ^          Now the + quantifier is useless
               ^   ^                    The + quantifier was useless
               ^   \w*(?:[.-]\w*)* seems to be equivalent to [\w.-]*
               The + quantifier was useless
```

If you want to restrict the range of `\w`:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9_.-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?@[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9_]*[A-Za-z0-9])?(?:[.-][A-Za-z0-9_]*[A-Za-z0-9])*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$
```

Comment: Note that `[^\W.-]` is the same as `\w`, the `\w` does not match `.` nor `-`, so there is no need to subtract these two chars from the `\w` pattern. Also, your regex does not match a valid `jasmin-martinez@teste-r.co`.

Comment: Yes I was alreadyabout to edit the answer. Thank you anyway.